# Is it possible to include document title from an included body file?

Tags: titles

I have a dozen or so course notes that I am writing. I have one 'styling file' (call it `Master.tex`) containing the header, and begin/end document - it specifies fonts, included packages, defined environments, etc. I then include the body of the document I want to compile. This way, all of my notes have the same styling, formatting, and feel.

However, the title of the document is declared in the header, which is in `Master.tex`. I would like to have a way to have this title be read off of the included body file - is this or something similar possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. However this all depends on _how_ you specify the title and how you want to access it.  So, really need you to compose a  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that shows how the title is specified as a complete file, and how you want to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `fancyhdr` package. (Edited to fix header formatting and to move `\title` to master file.)

```
% Master.tex
%
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\thisdocument}{to be replaced}

\title{\thisdocument}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead{} % clear defaults
\fancyhead[C]{\thisdocument}

\begin{document}

% included file contains the next lines
\renewcommand{\thisdocument}{What is the title of this lecture?}

\maketitle
\newpage
Header on this page is what it should be.

Some lecture notes here ...
% end of included material

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I changed the pagestyle to plain, though, as fancy was printing the title three times at the top of every other page.